# Script to Check Tunnels - Awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep, ipsec

im trying to figure out, b/c sometimes pings will work but thats b/c its just reg. ICMP but when real traffic tries to go through the tunnel it wont work b/c there are 2-3 tunnels up. I want to do an IF $tunnels > 1  AND $tunnels == 0 to do the below of restarting IPSec.

not that easy

```
#!/bin/bash

echo begin ping

ping -c 3 -w 3 -t 2 192.168.1.4 &> /dev/null ;

service ipsec status | awk 'NR==3' | cut -d" " -f1 $tunnels

if

        [ $? ==  0 ]

then
        echo "Connection is up" >> /root/restart_ipsec.log

else

        echo "Connection is down" >> /root/restart_ipsec.log

        date >> /root/restart_ipsec.log;

        /sbin/service crond stop >> /root/restart_ipsec.log;

        /sbin/service ipsec stop >> /root/restart_ipsec.log;

        sleep 120;

        /sbin/service ipsec start >> /root/restart_ipsec.log;

        /sbin/service crond start >> /root/restart_ipsec.log;

fi
```

i tried this BUT it keeps using the first if no matter what. even if i say the amount of tunnels is greater then 1 or 0 it still uses that statement. What gives!?

```
tunnels=$(service ipsec status | awk 'NR==3' | cut -d" " -f1 | sed -e 's/^[ ]*//')
a=0
if
        (( $tunnels > $a));
then
        echo "To many tunnels =" $tunnels >> /root/restart_ipsec2.log;
        echo $a;
elif
        [ $tunnels == 0 ]
then
        echo "To many tunnelss =" $tunnels >> /root/restart_ipsec2.log
elif
        echo "luis3";
        [ $? ==  0 ]
then
        echo "Connection is up" >> /root/restart_ipsec2.log
else
        echo "Connection is down" >> /root/restart_ipsec2.log
fi
```

Comment: `[ $? ==  0 ]` is testing whether or not `cut` succeeded. Is that what you want? Tell is in simple English what you're trying to do so we can try to help you.

Comment: the $? == 0 is asking if the ping replied or not, BUT i also need to find out how many tunnels ipsec has. if 1 thats ok, if more then 1 OR 0 for it to restart the service.

Comment: $? is the exit status of the last run command which is `cut` in your script, not `ping`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[ $? -eq 0 ]`, as it is a numeric comparision.

Also, this line:

```
service ipsec status | awk 'NR==3' | cut -d" " -f1 $tunnels
```

does not make many sense. If you want it to print the first field then do:

```
service ipsec status | awk 'NR==3{print $1}'
```

what I don't know is the use of `$tunnels` in the line you have.

Comment: im defining the variable $tunnels with the output of above. i tested it, so right now 1 tunnels up $tunnels will be 1. so if its more then 1 ex; 2 3 or 4 to restart ipsec OR if its 0 restart also.

Comment: The variable cannot be defined like that. You'd better do `tunnels=$(service ipsec status | awk 'NR==3{print $1}')`

Comment: hmm. that might be better yes. but im not sure b/c i do a if, else if else and i get errors.

Comment: So please update with proper explanation (don't use `b/c` but `because`, etc) and input / output. This way we will be able to trace your code in a better way.

Comment: So i have also the if and else statement that if the PING does not result is a proper reply to then restart. I am not sure where i can put the $tunnels > 1 statement in between the if and else statements.

Comment: Edited my post. hope that helps. i even tried -gt or (( > )) and nothing works.

Comment: Can you show the result of a simple `echo $tunnels` after the first line? So that I can see what is happenning.

Comment: If I hardcode `tunnels=1` I get inside the first `if` condition: `To many tunnels = 1`. Check if `$tunnels` is just "1" or it has some extra code that blocks the `if` condition.

Comment: i did, i made sure there are no spaces etc. still the first if condition should not happen. it should just pass to the next one.

Comment: I think I lost the reference of what is expected to be done. If `$tunnels=1` and `$a=0`, then it accomplishes the condition `(( $tunnels > $a));`

Comment: if the amount of tunnels > 1 then restart the server, $a=0 i was just tested because i thought 1 would not work.

Comment: i guess i would have to redo the whole thing =|

Comment: Just start with a basic script with basic conditions: `if [ $tunnels -ge 1 ]; then ... fi` and then keep giving more options. This way you will be able to find the errors easily.

Comment: @Luis update your question with your current code. Also, indicate the output of `service ipsec status` so I can know what can be in `tunnels` variable.